# My dog ate “Bonne Mammans Blackcurrant Conserve” the other day

Tags: dogs

My dog is about 3 and a half yrs and she ate a Blackcurrant sandwich with the conserve in the title. I’ve seen speculation online about the toxicity and difference between zante currants and Blackcurrant, but haven’t come to a specific conclusion. Furthermore, I don’t know if the conserve she ate was marketed as Blackcurrant but is actually zante currants. She hasn’t displayed any symptoms of renal failure (she’s seems a little tired, but she normally sleeps a lot). I don’t want tot ate any chances. Should I take her to the vet?

Comment: If in worry about the health of your pet, please do not wait for guesses of strangers. Go to the vet, or call them to ask about the blackcurrant vs zante currant!

Comment: Also have please a look into the following guide line about questions on the line "should I visit a vet?" : [on topic?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Allerleirauh while “call the vet” is usually a good hint, we can solve this specific dilemma - it’s a kitchen lingo issue based on the fact that a kind of small, dark raisins are called “currants” in English (“Korinthen” in Germany). The jam is made from black currants, not raisins.

Answer (score 4):

Blackcurrants are [*Ribes nigrum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackcurrant), [zante currants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zante_currant) are raisins made from dried Black Corinth grapes, a cultivar of [*Vitis vinifera*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitis_vinifera).

The confusion is based on the fact that the name of the grapes product “raisins de Corinth” got shortened and mangled a bit and in kitchen/baking lingo they are called “currants”, which is a misnomer. The naming problem exists only in English, other languages distinguish clearly.

The jam is made from fresh fruit, so actual blackcurrants (ribes), not raisins. I double-checked [the manufacturer’s website](https://www.bonnemaman.co.uk/products/conserves/blackcurrant-conserve) and it clearly lists blackcurrants. Food labeling laws wouldn’t allow zante currants to be used here.

So your dog is perfectly safe, she didn’t eat grapes and red & black currants are harmless (in moderation, of course).